# taxonomy terms array not working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, array

I'm working on a solution to filter a custom post type by multiple terms in multiple taxonomies.

Here is my code:

```
<?php $term = "peoria,adams"; ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <?php $term = explode(',', $term); ?>

        <?php $term_count = count($term); 
        $array_term = $term[0];
        ?>

        <?php 
            $i = 1;
            while ($i < $term_count) {
                $array_term = "'" . $array_term . "', '" . $term[$i] . "'";
                $i++;
            }
            ?>

        <?php echo $term = "array( ". $array_term . " )"; ?>

        <?php //echo $array_term; ?>

        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'property',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'Status',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array( 'Locked' )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'County',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' =>  $term
                    )
                )
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                the_title();
                echo '<div class="entry-content">';
                echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
                the_content();
                echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
        ?>
```

I echo `$term` and it display what it should display but it does not work when I call it in `'terms' => $term` it does not work but it will work if I replace it with `array( 'peoria', 'adams' )` it works.

I have a suspicion I'm doing something stupid but I'm just missing it. Can someone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
'terms' =>  $term
```

where in your case it's like:

```
'terms' =>  "array( 'peoria', 'adams' )"
```

but it should be like

```
'terms' =>  array( 'peoria', 'adams' )
```

By looking at your code snippet, you could try

```
'terms' =>  explode( ',', $term );
```

since `explode` will return the array you are looking for.

So you shouldn't construct the array as a string.

Check for example the *PHP* manual on **arrays** [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and **explode** [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).